# Choose an item in navigation bar and then it leads to showing a text in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am a beginner. I am trying to learn `JavaScript`, `HTML` and `CSS` simultaneously. I have written a test code which has a navigation bar and I would like that a paragraph of text will pop out in the page when I click on any of the items in the menu bar. I have written the following code but it doesn't work.
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--creating a navigation bar-->
<nav id="MyNavBar" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
 <ul id="details" class="nav navbar-nav">

<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Links
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul id="subdetails" class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="Something">Something</a></li>
        <li><a href="Others">Another thing</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>    
</ul>
</div>
</nav>    
<div class="background-image"></div>
<section id="content">

</section>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('#MyNavBar ul li a').click(function(){
                    $('#content').load('details.html #' + $(this).attr('href'));
                    return false;
                });

            });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.css**

```
body {
  font-family: "Serif";
}

.background-image {
  background: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CXAOHDfWMAU2Zmi.jpg");
  background-size: cover;     
  position: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  -webkit-filter:blur(3px) grayscale(50%);
  -ms-filter:blur(3px) grayscale(50%);
  filter:blur(3px) grayscale(50%);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Lobster;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    padding: 12px 16px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 0;
 }
#MyNavBar {
   background-color:goldenrod;
}
#details {
   background-color:goldenrod;
}
#subdetails {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

**details.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="Others">
    <h2>This is Another thing</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph of textual information about <b>Another thing</b> that will blow your mind.</p>
</div>
<div id="Something">
    <h2>This is Something</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph of textual information about <b>Something</b> that will blow your mind.</p>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make my code to show a text based on selection of an item in the menu?

Comment: What kind of debugging have you tried.  For example, do you know for sure that the click event fires?  If so, do you know that the jQuery selector is selecting the right element?  If so, do you know that the load method is returning what you expect?

Comment: @Seano666 The clicking doesn't do anything, that is the main problem.

Comment: It works, add `z-index: -1` to `.background-image`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `#content` is currently behind `.background-image` since `.background-image` is `position: fixed` - setting a non-`static` `position` creates a new stacking context with that element and gives it a default `z-index` so it will appear on top of non-`position`ed elements.

To move `.background-image` behind the rest of the content, add `z-index: -1`

Answer (score 0):

Change this code:

```
$('#content').load('details.html #' + $(this).attr('href'));
```

To this:

```
$('#content').load('details.html');
```

Then when you click on the "Links" element:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Links
    <b class="caret"></b>
</a>
```

It should load the content of `details.html` inside your section

Comment: do you have your `details.html` in the same folder of the html file you posted above?

Comment: I figured when I comment out the background with my code the text will appear. How can I make the text to appear on top of the background?

Comment: That issue is related to CSS you should define z-index to the content and the background-image